# how can i improve a graph with plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, graphic

I need to plot two arrays with data very close together. 
How can I improve the performance of the graphic
I would like to reduce the line plot.

[image]

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41574157/my_plot.png

Comment: Upload somewhere the pictures and link them here?

Comment: Place your image on a public sharing website and I will edit your post.  Also, what do you mean by "reducing the line plot"?

Comment: I added the link. I mean a less detailed chart...

Comment: What do you mean by "less detailed"?  Do you want to decrease the resolution of your data?

Comment: Yes,decrease the resolution or do an interpolation

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Smoothing the data? Take a look at moving averages.

Comment: I could try both, but I do not know how to do specially
 the moving averages that peraphs could be the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you either want to do some sort of interpolation, smoothing, or a subsampling of points.  Let's take a look at all approaches:

## Method 1 - Subsampling

This is pretty easy to do.  Supposing that both of your data points are stored in `x` and `y`, you can specify how often you want to sample from your data.  If you wanted to sample every 10 points as an example, you can do something like:

```
xsample = x(1:10:end);
ysample = y(1:10:end);
plot(xsample, ysample);
```

`plot` will linearly interpolate in between each of the points for you already.  This is the default behaviour of `plot`.

## Method 2 - Interpolating (not linear)

You can subsample your points like we did above, then use `interp1` to interpolate in between the "keypoints".  Let's assume you want to do a `spline` interpolation.  As such:

```
yinterp = interp1(xsample, ysample, x, 'spline');
plot(x, ysample);
```

## Method 3 - Smoothing

If you have the Curve Fitting Toolbox, you can use the `smooth` function.  The default behaviour of the `smooth` function is a moving average.  It basically takes your points within a finite sized window, averages them and that is the output for **one** sample.  The averaging gives you an output that is a smoothed version of your data.  The default window is of width 5, but you can specify whichever span you want.

```
ysmooth = smooth(y); %// or you can do ysmooth = smooth(y, N); 
                     %// where N is the size of your smoothing window
plot(x, ysmooth);
```

**NB:** `N` must be an **odd** number (1, 3, 5, etc.)

Hopefully one of these methods will work for you!

Comment: i'm sorry, but I do not have enough reputation to vote. I'm a new user